# CISCO Routers: Can't set Gateway of Last Resort

Tags: networking, router

I'm trying to set up a Gateway of Last Resort:

```
BRANCH1#config t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
BRANCH1(config)#ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.9.129
BRANCH1(config)#exit

%SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
BRANCH1#show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, I - IGRP, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     192.168.9.0/27 is subnetted, 2 subnets
C       192.168.9.64 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
C       192.168.9.96 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
```

On the third line I issue:

```
BRANCH1(config)#ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.9.129
```

I know the IP address is set right, and I don't get an error. Why would it still show the Gateway of last resort as not being set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your router doesn't know how to reach 192.168.9.129.  If that last subnet is 192.168.9.96/27 that falls short of the .129.  You can also make sure you have routing enabled ("ip routing" at global config)